# What is default ArcGIS raster calculator angular unit?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

Is the default arcgis raster calculator angular unit degrees or radians?

Comment: Have you consulted its documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Sin/009z000000nm000000/

•The input values for this tool are interpreted to be in radians. If the input you wish to use is in degrees, the values must first be divided by the radians-to-degrees conversion factor of 180/pi, or approximately 57.296.